# Can every isomorphism between a vector space and its dual be written as a non-degenerate bilinear form?

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, dual-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

If I have understood correctly, non-degeneracy of a bilinear form:

$$\omega:V\times V\rightarrow \Bbb F \tag{1},$$

in which $\Bbb F$ the underlying field of $V$, is a strong enough condition to conclude that $\omega$ provides an isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$: non-degeneracy $\Rightarrow$ trivial kernel $\Rightarrow$ injectivity $\Rightarrow$ surjectivity if dimesions are the same.

My question is does the converse hold, can all isomorphisms between a vector space and its dual be induced by *some* non-degenerate bilinear form on $V$?

Comment: In fact, every map $V \to V^*$ is induced by some bilinear form. See Hom-Tensor Adjunction.

Comment: Oh that's pretty cool thanks @QiZhu, is the subset of these forms that are non-degeneate exactly those that induce isomorphisms of the form $V\rightarrow V^*$?

Comment: Yes. It follows immediately after unravelling the definition.

Comment: @QiZhu Thanks for your help, I'm a physicist so I'm not extremely familiar with such things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f:V\to V^*$ is an isomorphism, and we define $\omega:V\times V\to \Bbb{F}$ as $\omega(v_1,v_2):= [f(v_1)][v_2]$, then $\omega$ is bilinear, and note that from the definition, we have that $\omega(v_1,\cdot)= f(v_1)$. In other words, the mapping $v_1\mapsto \omega(v_1,\cdot)$ is equal to $f$, which by assumption is an isomorphism of $V$ onto $V^*$.

If $V$ is infinite-dimensional, there are no isomorphisms $V\to V^*$, so the statement above becomes vacuous.

---

**Edit:**
The previous version of my answer made it seem like there was a distinction to be made (because it wasn't obvious to me in the case of non-symmetric/skew-symmetric bilinear forms). But, thanks to @Marc van Leeuven for pointing out that the distinction between left/right non-degeneracy is unnecessary.

For the sake of completeness, here's the proof of the equivalence. Let $\omega_l:V\to V^*$ be the left map, $x\mapsto \omega(x,\cdot)$, and let $\omega:V\to V^*$ be the right map $y\mapsto \omega(\cdot, y)$. Also, let $\iota:V\to V^{**}$ be the canonical map into the double dual. One can easily verify by unwinding definitions that
\begin{align}
\omega_r^*\circ \iota=\omega_l\quad\text{and} \quad\omega_l^*\circ\iota=\omega_r
\end{align}
where the stars on the maps indicate the dual/transposed mapping.
Now, make the assumption that $V$ is finite-dimensional. Then, $\iota$ is an isomorphism.
So, if $\omega_r$ is assumed an isomorphism, then so is $\omega_r^*$, and thus (by first equation) $\omega_l$ being the composition of two isomorphisms is as well. Similarly, $\omega_l$ being an isomorphism implies by the second equation that $\omega_r$ is.

One can also rephrase the argument using matrices since we're in finite dimensions, but I'd rather not :)

Comment: If $V$ is infinite dimensional then there are no isomorphisms $V\mapsto V^*$ for dimension reasons, so if one is going to use that criterion then there are no bilinear forms in infinite dimensional spaces. And in the finite dimensional case a bilinear form is left-degenerate if and only if it is right-degenerate.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen thank you for your comment. At the time of writing, I wasn't sure about the left-right equivalence, hence I added the second paragraph, though perhaps my language "One has to specify..." made it seem like a certainty. Though now in hindsight it's 'obvious', I'll edit now. Regarding the dimensionality, of course you're certainly right (though in the infinite-dimensional case where $V$ is a real/complex normed space, one usually refers to the topological dual, in which case we can talk about continuous maps and "weak/strong non-degeneracy", but let's not open that can of worms).