# Is nondegeneracy of a bilinear form equivalent for both slots?

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, dual-spaces

According to [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Degenerate_bilinear_form), a bilinear form $B$ on a (possibly infinite-dimensional) vector space $V$ is defined as nondegenerate if the map

$$B^\flat:V\ni x\mapsto B(x,\cdot)\in V^*$$

is an isomorphism onto its image, i.e., injective.$^\dagger$ It seems natural to also consider whether the map

$$B^\flat{'}:V\ni y\mapsto B(\cdot,y)\in V^*$$

is injective. **If $B$ is not assumed to be symmetric, are these two conditions equivalent?** Please give a proof or counterexample.

**Edit:** In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3974026/477746) answer, it was originally claimed that the implication is false, but then after an exchange in the comments here it was updated to reflect the fact that $B^\flat$ can never be a full isomorphism if $V$ is infinite dimensional. I think this leaves the question I'm asking here unanswered still.

---

$^\dagger$Actually, the above-linked Wiki article is a bit vague and even suggests that $B^\flat$ must be an isomorphism onto *all* of $V^*$, which—as Marc van Leeuwen points out in the comments—is impossible whenever $V$ is infinite dimensional. However, [this](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Dual_space#/Bilinear_products_and_dual_spaces) section of a different Wiki article suggests that the correct definition is as stated above.

Comment: The definition given in the WP article cannot be right in the infinite dimensional case, since in that case the fact that $\dim(V^*)>\dim(V)$ (as cardinal numbers) excludes the possibility of any isomorphism. Indeed [another WP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) writes that "the algebraic dual space is always of larger dimension (as a cardinal number) than the original vector space". The natural thing to require would appear to be an injective linear map $V\to V^*$ such that the intersection of all kernels of dual vectors in the image is the $0$-dimensional subspace of  $V$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I see. However, there is a way to salvage the question to make it meaningful again: Let's re-interpret the nondegeneracy condition to mean "isomorphic onto a subspace of $V^*$," i.e., injective.

Comment: In fact, the article you linked to seems to imply that this is the intended definition, claiming, "If the bilinear form is nondegenerate, then this is an isomorphism onto a subspace of $V^*$."

Comment: Under this definition, we only need to prove injectivity. However, my proof of injectivity in the post no longer works, because it assumed surjectivity of $B^\flat$, which we are no longer assuming. I'm updating the question to reflect all this.

Comment: I just edited my answer in the link, to reflect Marc van Leeuwen's comment about the equivalence of left/right non-degeneracy in the finite-dimensional case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't exactly know what is the final definition of non-degeneracy after the comments, so I will use the one given by the OP.

So, let $B$ be a bilinear form, $e_i$ be a basis for your vector space
and $a_{ij}=B(e_i,e_j)$, so if $x=\sum x^ie_i$, $y= \sum y^je_j$, where only finitely many $x^i$ and $y^j$ are nonzero,
$$B(x,y)=B \left( \sum_i x^i e_i , \sum_j y^j e_j\right)=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}x^iy^j$$
Note that the sum is finite because only finitely may of the $x^i$, $y^j$ are non-zero.

Let's briefly jump back to the finite dimensional case. The equation above can be written in matrix form:

$$B(x,y) = \bf x A y^t$$

Where $\bf A$ is the matrix formed by the $a_{ij}$, $\bf x$ and $\bf y$ are the (row) vectors formed by the $x^i$ and $y^j$ respectively, which will be identified with $x$ and $y$ . Note that one can recover $B$ from the matrix $\bf A$. Then, your maps are

$$ \flat x \mapsto \text{the map sending } y \text{ to } x \textbf{A} y^t $$
$$ \flat' y \mapsto \text{the map sending } x \text{ to } x \textbf{A} y^t $$

and my claim (which is more or less obvious) is that:

> The map sending $y$ to $x \textbf{A} y^t$ is non-zero if and only if $x \textbf{A}$ is nonzero

Therefore, $\flat$ is injective if for all $x$ different than $0$, $x \textbf{A}$ is different than $0$. This is the definition of regularity: A matrix $M$ is regular by the left if $NM=0$ implies $N=0$.

In a similar fashion we prove the analogue result for $\flat '$, and therefore

> $\flat $ (resp. $\flat '$) is injective iff $\bf A$ is regular by the left (resp. right)

Now, we have a theorem in linear algebra saying that a matrix is regular by the ñeft iff it is regular by the right iff it is invertible. Therefore, in finite dimensions, $\flat$ is injective iff $\flat '$ is injective.

How do I carry the same argument in infinite dimension? Let $\{e_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a basis for your vector space. In this case, $I$ is an infinite set. If you want to visualize it, think of $I = \mathbb N$. Now, a *row vector* will be a collection of scalars $(x^i)_{i \in I}$, such that only finitely many of them are nonzero, and it represents the vector $\sum_i  x^i e_i$. A *matrix* will be any set of scalars $a_{ij}$ indexed by $(i,j) \in I \times I$. In this setting, things like $(x^i ) \cdot (a_{ij})$ or $(x^i) \cdot (a_{ij}) \cdot (y^j)^t$ can be made have sense. for instance, the first one would be a uple indexed by $I$ whose $j$-th entry is $\sum_i x^ia_{ij}$, but it is not a row vector because it may have infinitely many nonzero entries.

Anyways, the same ideas as before can be applied: $B$ can be associated with a matrix $\textbf{A}=(a_{ij})$, $\flat $  ( resp. $\flat '$) is injective iff $\bf A$ is regular  by the left (resp. right).

However, in infinite dimension they are not equivalent. This is the equivalent to saying that in infinite dimension one can have an endomorphism which is injective but not surjective. The classical example is the shift operator, which is defined by the (infinite) matrix over $\mathbb N$ having $0$ everywhere except $1$'s on top of the diagonal. Now, you can try to formalize all of this, and I won't blame you for trying it, but I think it is more important to convince yourself that it actually works.

However, as you said, I will give you the explicit construction. Let $V$ be the vector space consisting of uples $(a_1, a_2, \ldots)$ where $a_i \in k$ and only finitely many of the $a_i$ are nonzero. Let $B\left( (a_i), (b_i)\right)$ be equal to $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{i}b_{i+1}$. You can check easily that it is a bilinear form, that $B(x,\cdot)$ is never $0$ if $x$ is nonzero but that if $y=(1,0,0, \ldots)$ then $B(\cdot , y)$ is identically $0$.

Comment: I'm asking about the general case, where $V$ is not assumed to have finite dimension. I think this answer assumes finite dimension, otherwise we cannot form a square matrix with the $a_{ij}$?

Comment: I am answering for the general case. You can form a matrix of infinite dimension  whenever you have a basis. The easiest ones to visualize are basically matrices over a countable basis, since they are like an "infinite square". I am writing in this way because it is more visual and helps to give motivation. However, in the end my answer says: in finite dimension the two conditions are equivalent and here is a counterexample in infinite dimension. If you want I can write more explicitly the counterexample

Comment: I see. I would prefer seeing the counterexample more explicitly. I'm not familiar with the "regular" terminology—I get the idea, but it is unclear whether it requires a notion of inner product (which you use in the 3rd paragraph). In the infinite-dimensional case, it isn't clear whether $(a_{ij})\cdot(y^j)$, etc., makes sense. And anyway it seems sketchy to be using structure that is not originally assumed, at least without proof that such structure must exist.

Comment: I have edited the answer to have more motivation form matrices in finite dimensional vector spaces. I was trying to prove formally everything in infinite dimensions but if gets kind of messy to be honest. I also included the specific example. If you don't get the idea of what $V$ is, it is like the vector space of polynomails over $k$ or arbitrary degree.

Comment: Got it, the counterexample at the end is what I was looking for. Thanks!